# Get parent property on PHP

Tags: php

```
MySuperCooLFunction($object->property1->property2->property3);
```

...

```
public function MySuperCooLFunction($args) {
   // retreive property 3
   // retreive property 2
   // retreive property 1
}
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Why parent property, I don't see any inheritance here. You just pass an object to a function... well, if you do that, the object is available inside the function. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

No, you probably want to do something like this instead

```
MySuperCooLFunction($object);
...

public function MySuperCooLFunction($object) {
   $object->property1 // retreive property 1
   $object->property1->property2 // retreive property 2
   $object->property1->property2->property3 // retreive property 3
}
```

if you don't want to pass $object in for some reason,

```
   public function MySuperCooLFunction($property1) {
       $property1 // property 1 is passed in
       $property1->property2 // retreive property 2
       $property1->property2->property3 // retreive property 3
    }
```

also works

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if your property-objects store their parent object in one of their own properties, since you are only passing the value of `property3` to `MySuperCooLFunction()` I would not recommend that, though (this would lead to quite inflexible code). Why don't you pass `$object` to `MySuperCooLFunction()`? You can access all properties when working from the top down.

Comment: Yes i know, im just trying to save codelines from down to top, but i'll try to do a workaround.

Comment: @alexandre: Do not try to compress your code so much that simple things look complicated. It is not worth it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not a way for the function (as written) to get the values of `object`, `property1` or `property2`.

When `MySuperCooLFunction($object->property1->property2->property3)` is called, only the *value* of `property3` is passed as the argument. When the call is made, the interpreter resolves `$object->property1->property2->property3` to the value of `property3` then hands that value into the function. The function has no knowledge of how the value of the argument was found/computed.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this. When your function is invoked, you are making a copy of property3 (in case it is a simple variable) or a reference to it, but you loose the references to the rest of the parent object.

If you want to do that, you need to convert property3, and property2, and property1, into objects which have a parent field which points to the parent.